# Tortoise SVN 1.9.7 not saving password

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have installed Tortoise SVN is 1.9.7 on Windows 2012 R2.
Even though I have saved the credentials each time I do any action on SVN its keeps on prompting for password.

In Subversion Configuration file I have set

```
password-stores = windows-CryptoAPI
password-stores = yes
store-passwords = yes
store-auth-creds = yes
```

Also from TortoiseSVN settings -> Saved Data -> Clear Authentication data 
Have deleted %APPDATA%\Subversion\auth and tried saving the data again but its still asking for password.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Avinash

Comment: Did the answer help?

Answer (score 0):

You should read the documentation and double-check what you've entered into the `config` file. Some of the settings are invalid, as far as I see.

Note that normally you don't need to adjust the `config` file on Windows for SVN to store the credentials. You'd better contact the server admin for assistance -- check what's logged to the server's log when you reproduce the password prompt.